# Posting comment toa facebook plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, plugins, sdk, comments

We have a website in which facebook plugin is been integrated.
I could able to fetch comments from the plugin using the graph API. But when I tried to post the comment its giving
"Comment may not be added to plugin".

Could anybody please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: “Comment may not be added to plugin” – that is your answer already; it is currently not possible to publish a comment onto an external Open Graph object.

Comment: As @Cbroe stated, I don't think the comment plugin supports publishing comments via the API.